# How to remove splash screen on logout button or link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created splash screen on jquery It's working fine on load page.when i logout the page.It's same thing repeated again.I want to remove splash animation when i logout how I can do?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#splash').addEventListener('transitionend', (event) => {
    event.target.remove();
  });

  document.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('transitionend', (event) => {
    event.target.remove();
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    document.querySelector('#splash').classList.add('slide-out-fwd-center');

    $('#splash').delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('#splash').hide();
      $('.content').css({
        'display': 'block',
        'animation': 'popup 0.5s ease-in-out 1'
      });
    });
  });
});


Here is logout button which i am using .content is linking to login page
    <a href="login.php" class="innerrestart" id="stop">Logout</a>
```

Comment: @SuperModel  it's not working It will be work on click.i mentioned here  on load code I want to remove this animation when i click logout button but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery, you can remove or hide any thing by class or specific id

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $( ".className" ).remove();
 });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add jquery file, If not added yet.

Using CSS you can hide elements/controls by class name or id

```
.className{ display:none;}
    //if have id
    #idName{ display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another class on class="content" that will specify if a user is logged in or not. then select it with $('.content.loggedin') or $('.content.loggedout')